# Getting Error Code: 1064 while creating Stored Procedure in Mysql8.0

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here is my simple code to create stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure GetemployeeDetails
As
Select * from OrderDetails
Go
```

Getting error as Create Procedure GetemployeeDetails AS Select * from OrderDetails Go

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS Select * from OrderDetails Go' 
at line 2   0.000 sec.
```

I am using MySql workbench version 8.0. Can anyone tell me which is correct syntax for this?

Comment: You really should read the manual before posting. and BTW there is no GO in mysql that's a sqlserver thang. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Do not use MS SQL syntax on MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetemployeeDetails()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM OrderDetails ;
END $$

Comment: Why not test before posting.That way you will know rather than think.